# What sort of mathematical object is a stochastic process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

My introductory stochastic processes course uses $\{Q(t); T>=0\}$ (in particular, please note the semicolon) to refer to a random process, where $Q(t)$ is a time-dependent variate.    Conceptually, this object seems to be a sequence, right? But my course notes claim that "mathematically, a random process is a **collection**[emphasis mine] of random variables in either continuous time/space or discrete time/space"-- so which is it?  In any case, is the given notation standard? Does the notation mean that a random process is a set or that it's a sequence, or what?

ps. It doesn't sound right to me for a random process to be a set, since (a) the order of the elements is important yet the ordering of the elements is irrelevant for sets, and (b) the variate is allowed to take on multiple identical values but if the process were a set these values would be conflated as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stochastic process $Q$ defined on some index set $T$ is a mapping $Q:\Omega\times T\to S$, $(\omega,t)\mapsto Q(\omega,t)$, where $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ is a probability space, $(S,\mathcal S)$ is a measurable space, for example $(S,\mathcal S)=(\mathbb R^d,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d))$, and each function $Q_t:\Omega\to(S,\mathcal S)$, $\omega\mapsto Q(\omega,t)$, is $(\mathcal F/\mathcal S)$-measurable.

One can use the notations $Q=(Q_t)_{t\in T}$ or $Q=(Q(t))_{t\in T}$, the notation $\{Q(t);t\in T\}$ being (also used but) more dubious for the reasons you explain..

Comment: If $T=\mathbb N$, a sequence. In the general case, what I wrote (which could get you "wiser" if you read it carefully).

Comment: First sentence of my answer: is $Q$ qualified as a "set" in any way? Hence what?

Comment: I'm lost. The measure-theoretic answer is all new to me; the only thing I know is that a space is a set with attached mappings/properties. I just don't get why a random process is defined as a collection (yes I do know that everything can be exhibited as sets, but I doubt my course is trying to be set-theoretical about this), and the given notation with the semicolon is not clueing me in as to what the author's actual mathematical conception of "random process" is.

Comment: Forget the measure theory. One needs a function $Q$ defined on $\Omega\times T$.

Comment: We do have such a function, yes.

Comment: ((At least two comments deleted by the OP.))

Comment: Thanks, the last sentence in your answer has answered my question exactly.